# Packaging GWT module jar

Tags: gwt

I have created a GWT-loadable module (maven) with this output jar structure (using mvn package command):

```
mygwtlibrary
->src/main/java
-->org.mygwtlib
---->public
------>flash.swf
-->org.mygwtlib.client
---->MyClientCode.class
```

However when I run a application that use this library, error shows: `Error 404` for fetching the `flash.swf` file.

Here's the scenario:

- I have setup the project properly, including the `<inherits>` in the gwt.xml file
- When I just include the whole library project into another GWT application project then run, it works fine. That is, the files from the public folder is loaded too.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to fetch the `flash.swf` file over HTTP. This is (at best) bad practice. A better approach (by no means the only alternative) would be pulling it in as a resource which lives in your code. One way to do such a thing would be using Spring's [`ClassPathResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) (or less preferably, `FileSystemResource`).

Comment: Although what I did was to pass on GWT.getModuleBase to the javascript function that does the fetching of the swf file. However I think your answer is appropriate